# Java BufferedWriter very slow - 300 MB of data

Tags: java

I'm reading a text file consisting of fixed length records line by line and append some values and then write to another file.

As usual, I used BufferedWriter, and found that it takes around 20 Mins to read, append values and write to another file.

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
if (br != null) {
    for (String line; (line= br.readLine()) != null;) {
        i= i+ 1;
        line += "    " + String.format("%09d", i) + "S";
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt",
                    true));
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the code I have used. Reading the whole file and appending the values takes just 7 seconds, but writing to file seems to be slow. I know BufferedWriter cannot be this much slower. I didnt increase the buffer size as i'm reading line by line and for the same reason didnt try nio.

Suggest me some way to improve the speed?

Comment: You need to create a new bufferedwriter, open and close a filewriter through it for every single line of input you process?

Comment: You reopen the file every line...
How about, just open it once before the loop ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got *at least* two problems here:

- You're reopening the output file on each iteration. That's pretty much bound to be slow. Open it once at the same time you open the reader.
- You're not closing either the reader or the writer on exceptions. Use `try-with-resources` blocks (Java 7) or `try/finally` blocks (pre-Java 7)

The latter won't be a performance problem, but it could break other code that expects the files to be closed.

Additionally, I would strongly recommend against using either `FileReader` or `FileWriter`, as both use the platform default encoding without letting you specify anything else. If you're using Java 7, use `Files.newBufferedReader` and `Files.newBufferedWriter` which:

- Are shorter in terms of code
- Use UTF-8 by default (which is often the best option)
- Allow you to specify the encoding if you want something else

Comment: @StephenC Updated the question. Sorry.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have to use Java 6.

Comment: @Harbinger: Please note that in the question in future. Increasingly, answers are likely to assume Java 7+ unless otherwise specified - it was released in 2011, after all. (I'd strongly recommend pushing for an upgrade, on a separate note...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure Jon. Thanks for the note.

Comment: TBH, as of May 2015 I'd be tempted to assume Java *8*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69813/discussion-between-sean-reilly-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new bufferedwriter, then opening and closing a filewriter through it for every single line of input you process.

Instead, create bw before the for loop and close it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 reasons make your code run slow:

1. You create file `outputstream` every time you write a single line.
2. You use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter to read and write line by line

Try this code:

```
public void copyFile() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("in.txt"));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.txt"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    fos.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Using `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream` and `buffer` you can control your read write speed by increase or decrease size of `buffer`.